# how to copy mean values of groupby in all applicable rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm following [this](http://blog.kaggle.com/2017/01/23/a-kaggle-master-explains-gradient-boosting/) example and I want to replay using Pandas. Unfortunately I'm almost immediately stuck: I don't know how to add a column with the mean values per category for all rows.

My dataframe:

```
ages = pd.DataFrame(
[[13, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
[14, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], 
[15, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], 
[25, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
[35, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
[49, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[68, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
[71, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[73, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]], columns=['age', 'gardening', 'gameing', 'hats'])
```

I want to add a column with mean age for all persons who (don't) do gardening:

```
ages['ma'] = ages.groupby('gardening')['age'].mean()
```

but this gives:

```
19.5
57.2
6 x NaN
```

and I want (the first column)

```
            gardening      age
19.5         0             13
19.5         0             14
19.5         0             15
57.2         1             25
19.5         0             35
57.2         1             49
57.2         1             68
57.2         1             71
57.2         1             73
 ^^
```

I tried broadcast, transform but this gives not the result I want. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Wen Well he is stating that he tried transform. I think however this is a dupe of something very similar. And tbh... we often jump quickly on answering instead of actually marking dupes, don't you agree?

Answer (score 5):

Use `groupby` with `transform`:

```
ages['avg_garden_age'] = ages.groupby('gardening')['age'].transform('mean')
ages
```

Output:

```
   age  gardening  gameing  hats  avg_garden_age
0   13        0.0      1.0   1.0           19.25
1   14        0.0      1.0   0.0           19.25
2   15        0.0      1.0   0.0           19.25
3   25        1.0      1.0   1.0           57.20
4   35        0.0      1.0   1.0           19.25
5   49        1.0      0.0   0.0           57.20
6   68        1.0      1.0   1.0           57.20
7   71        1.0      0.0   0.0           57.20
8   73        1.0      0.0   1.0           57.20
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `np.bincount` and the fact that `gardening` column is already `0` and `1`

```
def grp_mean(bins, weights):
    counts = np.bincount(bins)
    sums = np.bincount(bins, weights)
    return (sums / counts)[bins]

ages.assign(avg_garden_age=grp_mean(ages.gardening.values.astype(int), ages.age))

   age  gardening  gameing  hats  avg_garden_age
0   13        0.0      1.0   1.0           19.25
1   14        0.0      1.0   0.0           19.25
2   15        0.0      1.0   0.0           19.25
3   25        1.0      1.0   1.0           57.20
4   35        0.0      1.0   1.0           19.25
5   49        1.0      0.0   0.0           57.20
6   68        1.0      1.0   1.0           57.20
7   71        1.0      0.0   0.0           57.20
8   73        1.0      0.0   1.0           57.20
```